# pydev: find all references to a function

Tags: python, pydev

This has probably been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer. I've moved from windows to Linux and started using PyDev (Aptana) recently but what I cannot seem to find is how to find all references to a function.

Comment: What are you looking for that Ctrl+f doesn't provide?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+G will find all the references to a function in PyDev (F3 will go to the definition of a function).

Comment: I wish they would add this to the right click menu (Like it is in Java).

Comment: Please create a feature request for that.

Comment: For those on a Mac, it is Cmd+Shift+G

Comment: At least in my environment, it does not find references, it acts as a string search. For example it displays every occurence of "_ _ init _ _" in every file, instead of PyCharm showing the place where the object is created.

Comment: same behavior as @this.myself

Comment: It does not find all references. Maybe it does, but only in current file. I want a project search. So this is not the answer(or maybe the question itself is not properly worded).

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+G does find all the references in the workspace, if it doesn't work for your specific use case, it may be a misconfiguration or a bug in your specific use case (if that's the case, report it at the tracker).

Comment: I'm finding that Ctrl-Shift+G finds all referenced to the selected word not uses of the function.l I select a function's name in the def statement and press Ctrl-Shift+G and I get apparently every occurrence of that word in my workspace, in comments and literal strings too and variables of the same name in other files etc.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is F3. If not all of the key bindings for pydev are listed at:
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html