# How to search for Usages of a Function in Aptana?

Tags: aptana, pydev

In `PyCharm` its possible to search for usages of a particular Function, to see where else it is being called in the application.

Is such thing also implemented in `Aptana Studio 3.1.2 (PyDev)`?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731324/pydev-find-all-references-to-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do Ctrl+Shift+G to find references. See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html

Comment: At least in my environment, it does not find references, it acts as a string search. For example it displays every occurence of 
    __init__ 
in every file, instead of PyCharm showing the place where the object is created.